# Decrypt CryptoJS using Laravel with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, lumen, cryptojs

Im trying to decrypt string made by CryptoJs, How do i achieve this?

Here is my Js code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script>
   const key = localStorage.getItem('key')

   ...
   content = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(fileContent, key).toString();
   ...
</script>
```

now how do i decrypt it in laravel?
Here is my code so far:

```
$cipher = "aes-256-cbc"; // idk what is this
$key = $request->key;
$value = $request->value;
$encrypter = new Encrypter($key, $cipher);
```

Comment: CryptoJS uses the key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` when the key material is passed as string to derive key and IV. Also, `toString()` returns the result in OpenSSL format (ASCII encoding of `Salted__` + 8 bytes salt + ciphertext). On the Laravel side, this key derivation is completely missing, as well as the formatting of the data as [required by Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/be2ddb5c31b0b9ebc2738d9f37a9d4c960aa3199/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L118) (and of course the decryption itself, i.e. the call to `decrypt()` or `decryptString()`).

Comment: Maybe you can use library that created by brainfoolong in github. https://github.com/brainfoolong/cryptojs-aes-php

Answer (score 0):

The main steps have already been described in the comments:

- An `EVP_BytesToKey()` PHP implementation is needed. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ezimuel/67fa19030c75052b0dde278a383eda1b) a lightweight but sufficient implementation can be found (sha256 has to be replaced by md5, since CryptoJS uses md5).
- Salt and ciphertext are to be separated.
- Key and IV are to be derived.
- The ciphertext is to be decrypted.

```php
// -> replace 'U2FsdGVkX1...' with your data and 'some key material' with your passphrase...
// separate salt and ciphertext
$cryptoJSData = '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';
$cryptoJSDataRaw = base64_decode($cryptoJSData);
$salt = substr($cryptoJSDataRaw, 8, 8);
$value = substr($cryptoJSDataRaw, 16);
// derive key and IV
$keyIv = EVP_BytesToKey($salt, 'some key material');
$key = substr($keyIv, 0, 32);
$iv =  substr($keyIv, 32);
// decrypt
$cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
$decrypted_openssl = openssl_decrypt($value, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

function EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password) {
    $bytes = '';
    $last = '';

    // 32 bytes key + 16 bytes IV = 48 bytes.
    while(strlen($bytes) < 48) {
        $last = hash('md5', $last . $password . $salt, true);
        $bytes.= $last;
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

If you prefer Laravel/Encrypter for decryption, you must additionally:

- fake the MAC, since Laravel/Encrypter authenticates, unlike CryptoJS.
- Convert the data to Laravel/Encrypter format.

In the code above, replace the *decrypt*-part (i.e. the `openssl_decrypt()`-call) with:

```php
// fake MAC
$iv =  base64_encode($iv);
$value = base64_encode($value);
$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $iv.$value, $key);
$tag = '';
// apply Laravel/Encrypter format
$laravelFormat = base64_encode(json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac', 'tag'), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
// decrypt
$cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
$encrypter = new Encrypter($key, $cipher);
$decrypted_laravel = $encrypter->decryptString($laravelFormat);
```